# Model query on ForeignKey field

Tags: django, model

Is it possible to get a query set based on a related models field.

pseudo code:

```
#models.py
class Model1(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)

# Get all model2 entries where model1.a == foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
objects = Model2.objects.filter(model1__a='foo')
```

Comment: Well, that was simple. Thank you!